# Office 365 Mail Contact

Tags: powershell, office365

Does anyone know why the New-MailContact powershell command is not possible to insert a mail contact to ExchangeOnLine with the same name, while manually with office admin exchange center is possible?

The powershell error is as follows:
[The object 'CN=Pippo Franco,OU=tenantname.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=EURPR000000,DC=prod,DC=outlook,DC=com' already exists.]

In fact there is already contact Pippo Franco, as external Mail Contact, but it can happen that there are contacts outside the company with the same name but with different email address.

Any idea to charge these contacts at the same name with bulk powershell and not manually?

Any thoughts about that?

Regards.